# Opening Browser keeps adding more tabs

Tags: launcher, brave, tabs

I'm using Kubuntu (Ubuntu using KDE), and have run into an odd issue.  For work I have to use Microsoft OneNote.  As there is no native Linux app, I run it in the browser.  I'm one of those people that doesn't like to run various apps in browser tabs in the same window, so I use different browsers to open apps and leave them open in separate monitors (I have 4).

In one monitor, I use "Brave Browser" to open OneNote.  I have the launcher icon set to open the URL when clicked, and it's the only thing I use Brave for.

The application launcher icon uses this as the "Command" entry..

```
/usr/bin/brave-browser-stable %U https://<<REDACTED URL FOR MY ONENOTE >>
```

For quite a while, it worked fine.  Then about 60 days ago when I launched it in the AM there were 2 tabs.  I closed the second tab and logged in.  For some reason, it has kept expanding over time.  As of right now, there are 8 tabs in the AM when I launch it.

[image]

The tabs that say "Error..." are just from MS saying something went wrong.

[image]

I've tried everything I can think of, but I cannot prevent it from launching these additional tabs.

Any thoughts?

***Edited to add...***

I'm running Brave version 1.63.174.
Installed directly from the apt repos.
[image]

@guiverc Here's for your questions.

1. I'm using Kubuntu.  Which is why I see this...
   → lsb_release -a
   No LSB modules are available.
   Distributor ID: Ubuntu
   Description:    Ubuntu 22.04.4 LTS
   Release:    22.04
   Codename:   jammy
2. I have brave-browser installed via apt using the following repo...

→ pwd
/etc/apt/sources.list.d

→ cat brave-browser-release.list

deb [signed-by=/usr/share/keyrings/brave-browser-archive-keyring.gpg arch=amd64] https://brave-browser-apt-release.s3.brave.com/ stable main

3. I am not using snap AT ALL.

→ snap list

Command 'snap' not found, but can be installed with:
sudo apt install snapd

Anything else you want to know?

Comment: Providing your release may make it easier for people to help you (*I have no experience with `brave` so cannot; but even if I did you've provided few details as to your software stack as release is the starting point even if you've not using backports etc*)

Comment: You've added details about `brave`, but `brave` is **not** a application found in Ubuntu repositories (*for any supported release*), and you've still not provided release details yet (about your Ubuntu/Kubuntu system); are you using Ubuntu? or Kubuntu?  (*Kubuntu uses Ubuntu repositories*)   There is a copy of `brave` found in the *snapstore* but you mention *apt* repositories (not *snap*)

Comment: Added more info above.  Want anything else?

Comment: Your details show a *very modified* system **if** it was a Ubuntu system at all. You're using a 3rd party source which is why it was a *deb* package (Kubuntu/Ubuntu repositories only provide *snap* package with no *deb* available). Your details don't match a Kubuntu/Ubuntu system so I can't/won't help (they better match a Ubuntu-based system that isn't Ubuntu, or a heavily modified system of which you've given no details; KDE Neon for example)

Comment: You're way off.  This system is actually pretty plain-jane.  Kubuntu was installed directly from the 22.04 Jammy .iso downloaded directly from the website.

Yes, I did disable snapd, and installed brave from the repo mentioned above.  As to "highly-modified", that just isn't the case.  I'd say "slightly-modified" since snapd is disabled.

However, if you do not wish to assist, then I thank you for the time you've spent so far, and bid you adieu.